# Trying to understand the role of interface in inheritance between two classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I want to understand the role interface plays in inheritance between two classes.

My understanding is that you can create superclass and subclass with the use of `extends`.

```
class Parent {
}
class Child extends Parent {
}
```

This is already sufficient in creating superclass and subclass.

When do we need interface? Do we need `implements` for Child or Parent?

```
class Parent {
}
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface {
}
interface MyInterface {
}
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Why not read a Java tutorial about Object Orientation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29 has a pretty good explanation about why interfaces are handy, and how you use them.

Comment: What do you mean "*Do we need implements for Child or Parent*"?

Comment: Chris, this question arose from reading [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Comment: Lion, I am not sure if `implements` keyword is applied to Chile or Parent, or both.

Comment: It applies to the class you are defining, as if the `extends [superclass]` wasn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance and interface implementation defines a *is-a* relationship. This means that is the subclass A extends a superclass B, A *is-a* B. If the superclass B implements the interface I, B *is-a* I. And since A *is-a* A, A *is* also *a* I.

For example, a Car (ssuperclass) is a Vehicle (interface). Since Audi extends Car, Audi is also a Vehicle.

A subclass can not be less than its parent, but it can be more. So a child may implement interfaces that its parent class doesn't implement.

For example, all cars are not hybrid (interface). But this doesn't prevent a Prius, which is a Car, to be a hybrid. A Prius is more than just a Car. It's also a hybrid.

Comment: Thank you for the succinct analogy.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface MyInterface {
}

class Parent implements MyInterface{
}
class Child extends Parent {
       // Implements MyInterface because it's parent does
}
class Child2 extends Parent implements AnotherInterface {
       //  Child2 class now implements both
       // MyInterface as well as AnotherInterface
}
```

Not sure if you are asking about extending an interface, but that is also possible:

```
interface MyInterface {
}

interface MySecondInterface extends MyInterface {
}
```

You implement an interface when you want your class to use the constants described and define the method signatures contained in the interface.

So, if you want your PARENT class to use the constants and define the methods, then your PARENT implements the interface. If you want your CHILD class class to use the constants and define the methods, then your CHILD implements the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a class inheriting from a base class is independent of a class implementing an interface. In the first case, the inheriting class acquires both the interface and the implementation of its base "for free"; in the second case, a class is *checked* to comply with the interface that it is declared to implement.

A subclass inherits the interfaces that its base implements, but it is also free to implement additional interfaces. This is very convenient when classes in a single hierarchy must assume multiple roles, depending on their place in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Basically an interface is used to create guidelines for classes that implement it.

The main diffrences between an interface and a parent class are
1) You cannot instantiate the interface(it doesn't even have a constructor)
2) All its methods must be abstract
3) You must override all interface methods in the class that implements it.